# How to get data from Persist Storage to NextJS SSR

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to use my access_token on nextjs with storage persist.

But doesnt work, I doesnt find anything,
How can I pass persist data to nextjs ssr?

```
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
...blablabla...
export const getServerSideProps = async(context) => {
  const { sef, group, concept } = context.query
  
  const access_token = await storage.getItem('access_token')

  return {
    props: {
      access_token: access_token ? access_token : 'anan'
    },
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Redux storage works in the browser, `getServerSideProps` executes on the server.